# How can I recover mersenne twister when only the part of the bits?

Tags: random-number-generator, pseudo-random-generator

https://github.com/tna0y/Python-random-module-cracker
Here, when we get 32*624 bits of outputs from Mersenne-twister we can recover Mersenne twister. My question is when we get the parts of the bits, how can we recover Mersenne twister? For example function `getrandbits` from python random module gives only part of the bits. Is it available to untwist it?

Comment: When you say "get only part of the bits", do you mean you get fewer than 32*624 bits?  Or, do you mean that you get that many bits, only not consecutively?

Comment: It means, only not consecutively

Comment: You need to be a **lot** more specific as to the sampling. If you sample at random, clearly you can't ever recover the state as the sequence will be driven by the sampling regime, not the Twister.

Answer (score -1):

Use this https://github.com/icemonster/symbolic_mersenne_cracker. It allows you to tell what parts you are missing from the usual 32-bit parts in order to submit non-consecutive ints.